# How to detect rectangle in a rectangle?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, computational-geometry, rectangles

I am having the co-ordinates of top-left corner and the bottom-right corner of a list of rectangles say (a,b) and (c,d). I want to detect and remove rectangles which are within a rectangle. Overlapping rectangles can stay.

I have a dataset of 10,000 rectangles and I want an efficient way to solve this problem.

Currently I am doing it this way,

```
import pandas

data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

l = list(range(len(data)-1))

for i in range(len(data)):
    length = len(l)
    if i >= length:
        break
    for j in range(i+1, length):
        if j >= len(l):
           break
        if (data.iloc[l[i]]['a'] >= data.iloc[l[j]]['a']) and (data.iloc[l[i]]['b'] <= data.iloc[l[j]]['b']) and (data.iloc[l[i]]['c'] <= data.iloc[l[j]]['c']) and (data.iloc[l[i]]['d'] >= data.iloc[l[j]]['d']):
           l.pop(j)
```

I have implemented this algorithm after sorting the dataset in descending order of the area of the rectangles as rectangles with bigger areas do not fit inside rectangles with smaller areas. Here, I am poping the index of the rectangle from the list l after detecting whether it is inside another rectangle. Each time an element is poped it reduces the iterations.

This is taking few hours to solve and I need an efficient way to solve it even for hundred thousand samples.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried checking out the shapely library?

Comment: No. I will have a look at it.

Comment: I'd expect doing 8 dictionary/list/dictionary lookups every time to be expensive, especially when you can get away with substantially less.

Comment: Yup! I made it uncessarily complex by taking a list of index et al. Could have added flags. But still a simple detection algorithm(same detection logic) with O(n^2) worst case will take around 2 hrs for 10,000 samples.

Comment: Your question lacks crucial information. What is the distribution of sizes of rectangles relatively to the area covered by the set of rectangles. Are the rectangles "relatively small" (then you could use something like binary space partitioning), or are they completely random and sometimes very large relatively to the whole area? Can you provide a piece of code that generates rectangles with the size distribution similar to your actual dataset?

Comment: The area of the rectangles is range from 1 to 10 in my dataset. I will have a look at BSP. Thank you, very useful.

Comment: https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.contains seems useful. Thank you.

Comment: I am just thinking aloud here for fun - please join in if you have any ideas... on a 2,000x2,000 pixel background, I can draw 100,000 rectangles, each in a unique colour, each under 64 pixels in area in a few milliseconds. I can then revisit each of those rectangles and see what colour it is after all other rectangles have been plotted. If the rectangle is still the same colour, it doesn't intersect any others. If it is entirely a new colour, it is inside another rectangle. If it is a mixture of colours, it must intersect... does this help? (@YvesDaoust)

Comment: Mmmm... the logic above is not quite right. A rectangle may still be the same colour because it was plotted last, so I guess I gave to blend with what is already there as I draw each rectangle to retain some of whatever was underneath.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little divide-and-conquer algorithm that you could try.

I assume that as soon as you can quickly enumerate every pair of
colliding rectangles, you can also check whether one is fully 
contained in the other in constant time.

So, we have only to find colliding rectangles.

First, generalize it as follows: assume that you have two sets
of rectangles `A` and `B`, and that you want to find only pairs
`(a, b)` such that rectangle `a` is from `A`, `b` is from `B`, 
and `a` and `b` intersect.

First, the idea. Consider the following example 
of two groups `A` and `B` of rectangles partially 
separated by a horizontal line `L`:

```
      +----+                    +-----+
      | A1 |                    |  B1 |
      |    |     +-----+        +-----+
      +----+     |  A2 |
                 +-----+     +-----+
                             |  A3 |
_____________________________|_____|________ L
                             |     |
         +-------------------+##+  |
         |                   |##|  |
         |     B2            +##|--+    
         |                      |
         +----------------------+
```

The line `L` subdivides the sets `A` and `B` into three subsets:

```
A above L: {A1, A2}         (short: A>L)
A intersects L: {A3}        (short: A=L)
A below L: {}               (short: A<L)


B above L: {B1}             (B>L)
B intersects L: {}          (B=L)
B below L: {B2}             (B<L)
```

Observe that only rectangles from the following groups can collide:

```
         A<L    A=L    A>L
B<L       y      y      N
B=L       y      y      y
B>L       N      y      y
```

That is, if we want to find all collisions between `A` and `B`, once we
have found a suitable line `L`, we can ignore the collisions between
`A<L` vs. `B>L` and `A>L` vs. `B<L`. Thus, we obtain the following divide-and-conquer algorithm: while `A` and `B` not empty, find a suitable line that (roughly) maximizes the number of eliminated collision checks, subdivide `A` and `B` into three groups each, recursively proceed with seven subgroup collisions, ignore two subgroup combinations.

Assuming that if the rectangles are "small", and the groups `A=L` and `B=L` are mostly empty, this will (roughly) cut the size of the sets in half in every step, and we thus obtain an algorithm that on average runs in something like `O(n*log(n))` instead of `O(n*n)`.

Once you have the general case for arbitrary `A` and `B`, take the entire set of rectangles `R` and run the algorithm with `A = R; B = R`.

Here is a rough sketch in Python:

```
def isSubinterval(aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd):
  return aStart >= bStart and aEnd <= bEnd

def intersects(aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd):
  return not (aEnd < bStart or aStart > bEnd)

class Rectangle:
  def __init__(self, l, r, b, t):
    self.left = l
    self.right = r
    self.bottom = b
    self.top = t

  def isSubrectangle(self, other):
    return (
      isSubinterval(self.left, self.right, other.left, other.right) and
      isSubinterval(self.bottom, self.top, other.bottom, other.top)
    )

  def intersects(self, other):
    return (
      intersects(self.left, self.right, other.left, other.right) and
      intersects(self.bottom, self.top, other.bottom, other.top)
    )

  def __repr__(self):
    return ("[%f,%f]x[%f,%f]" % (self.left, self.right, self.bottom, self.top))

def boundingBox(rects):
  infty = float('inf')
  b = infty
  t = - infty
  l = infty
  r = - infty
  for rect in rects:
    b = min(b, rect.bottom)
    l = min(l, rect.left)
    r = max(r, rect.right)
    t = max(t, rect.top)
  return Rectangle(l, r, b, t)

class DividingLine:
  def __init__(self, isHorizontal, position):
    self.isHorizontal = isHorizontal
    self.position = position

  def isAbove(self, rectangle):
    if self.isHorizontal:
      return rectangle.bottom > self.position
    else:
      return rectangle.left > self.position

  def isBelow(self, rectangle):
    if self.isHorizontal:
      return rectangle.top < self.position
    else:
      return rectangle.right < self.position

def enumeratePossibleLines(boundingBox):
  NUM_TRIED_LINES = 5
  for i in range(1, NUM_TRIED_LINES + 1):
    w = boundingBox.right - boundingBox.left
    yield DividingLine(False, boundingBox.left + w / float(NUM_TRIED_LINES + 1) * i)
    h = boundingBox.top - boundingBox.bottom
    yield DividingLine(True, boundingBox.bottom + h / float(NUM_TRIED_LINES + 1) * i)

def findGoodDividingLine(rects_1, rects_2):
  bb = boundingBox(rects_1 + rects_2)
  bestLine = None
  bestGain = 0
  for line in enumeratePossibleLines(bb):
    above_1 = len([r for r in rects_1 if line.isAbove(r)])
    below_1 = len([r for r in rects_1 if line.isBelow(r)])
    above_2 = len([r for r in rects_2 if line.isAbove(r)])
    below_2 = len([r for r in rects_2 if line.isBelow(r)])

    # These groups are separated by the line, no need to 
    # perform all-vs-all collision checks on those groups!
    gain = above_1 * below_2 + above_2 * below_1
    if gain > bestGain:
      bestGain = gain
      bestLine = line
  return bestLine

# Collides all rectangles from list `rects_1` with 
# all rectangles from list `rects_2`, and invokes
# `onCollision(a, b)` on every colliding `a` and `b`.
def collideAllVsAll(rects_1, rects_2, onCollision):
  if rects_1 and rects_2: # if one list empty, no collisions
    line = findGoodDividingLine(rects_1, rects_2)
    if line:
      above_1 = [r for r in rects_1 if line.isAbove(r)]
      below_1 = [r for r in rects_1 if line.isBelow(r)]
      above_2 = [r for r in rects_2 if line.isAbove(r)]
      below_2 = [r for r in rects_2 if line.isBelow(r)]
      intersect_1 = [r for r in rects_1 if not (line.isAbove(r) or line.isBelow(r))]
      intersect_2 = [r for r in rects_2 if not (line.isAbove(r) or line.isBelow(r))]
      collideAllVsAll(above_1, above_2, onCollision)
      collideAllVsAll(above_1, intersect_2, onCollision)
      collideAllVsAll(intersect_1, above_2, onCollision)
      collideAllVsAll(intersect_1, intersect_2, onCollision)
      collideAllVsAll(intersect_1, below_2, onCollision)
      collideAllVsAll(below_1, intersect_2, onCollision)
      collideAllVsAll(below_1, below_2, onCollision)
    else:
      for r1 in rects_1:
        for r2 in rects_2:
          if r1.intersects(r2):
            onCollision(r1, r2)
```

Here is a little demo:

```
rects = [
  Rectangle(1,6,9,10),
  Rectangle(4,7,6,10),
  Rectangle(1,5,6,7),
  Rectangle(8,9,8,10),
  Rectangle(6,9,5,7),
  Rectangle(8,9,1,6),
  Rectangle(7,9,2,4),
  Rectangle(2,8,2,3),
  Rectangle(1,3,1,4)
]

def showInterestingCollision(a, b):
  if a is not b:
    if a.left < b.left:
      print("%r <-> %r collision" % (a, b))

collideAllVsAll(rects, rects, showInterestingCollision)
```

At least in this case, it indeed detects all the interesting collisions:

```
[1.000000,6.000000]x[9.000000,10.000000] <-> [4.000000,7.000000]x[6.000000,10.000000] collision
[1.000000,5.000000]x[6.000000,7.000000] <-> [4.000000,7.000000]x[6.000000,10.000000] collision
[4.000000,7.000000]x[6.000000,10.000000] <-> [6.000000,9.000000]x[5.000000,7.000000] collision
[6.000000,9.000000]x[5.000000,7.000000] <-> [8.000000,9.000000]x[1.000000,6.000000] collision
[7.000000,9.000000]x[2.000000,4.000000] <-> [8.000000,9.000000]x[1.000000,6.000000] collision
[2.000000,8.000000]x[2.000000,3.000000] <-> [8.000000,9.000000]x[1.000000,6.000000] collision
[2.000000,8.000000]x[2.000000,3.000000] <-> [7.000000,9.000000]x[2.000000,4.000000] collision
[1.000000,3.000000]x[1.000000,4.000000] <-> [2.000000,8.000000]x[2.000000,3.000000] collision
```

---

Here is a somewhat more realistic demo:

```
from random import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def randomRect():
  w = random() * 0.1
  h = random() * 0.1
  centerX = random() * (1 - w)
  centerY = random() * (1 - h)
  return Rectangle(
    centerX - w/2, centerX + w/2,
    centerY - h/2, centerY + h/2
  )

randomRects = [randomRect() for _ in range(0, 500)]

for r in randomRects:
  plt.fill(
    [r.left, r.right, r.right, r.left], 
    [r.bottom, r.bottom, r.top, r.top],
    'b-',
    color = 'k',
    fill = False
  )

def markSubrectanglesRed(a, b):
  if a is not b:
    if a.isSubrectangle(b):
      plt.fill(
        [a.left, a.right, a.right, a.left], 
        [a.bottom, a.bottom, a.top, a.top],
        'b-',
        color = 'r',
        alpha = 0.4
      )
      plt.fill(
        [b.left, b.right, b.right, b.left], 
        [b.bottom, b.bottom, b.top, b.top],
        'b-',
        color = 'b',
        fill = False
      )

collideAllVsAll(randomRects, randomRects, markSubrectanglesRed)

plt.show()
```

The plot shows all eliminated rectangles in red, and the enclosing rectangles in blue:

[image]

Here is a visualization of the bounding boxes (yellow) and chosen dividing lines (cyan) of the quasi-binary space partitioning for a small example with a single collision:

[image]

For 10000 "reasonably sized" random rectangles (with rate of intersection roughly as in the image), it computes all collisions in 18 seconds, even though the code is very far from being optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is one of spatial proximity, as such I would suggest you consider indexing your data spatially. That is store or index your rectangles in such a way that querying spatial relationships is cheap. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) for the most common data structures.

I implemented a demo using an R-tree. The entire "algorithm" consists of the following function. It is not particularly elegant as each unique collision is investigated twice. This is mostly due to the limited access and query interfaces the used `rtree` library provides.

```
import rtree  
def findCollisions(rects, onCollision):
    idx = rtree.index.Index(interleaved=False)
    for rect in rects:
        idx.insert(rect.id, rect.coords)

    for rect in rects:
        ids = idx.intersection(rect.coords)
        for hit in [randomRects[j] for j in ids]:
            onCollision(rect, hit)
```

The surrounding infrastructure I copied shamelessly from @AndreyTyukin with only slight modifications:

```
from random import random

def isSubinterval(aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd):
  return aStart >= bStart and aEnd <= bEnd

def intersects(aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd):
  return not (aEnd < bStart or aStart > bEnd)

class Rectangle:
  id = 0
  def __init__(self, l, r, b, t):
    self.left = l
    self.right = r
    self.bottom = b
    self.top = t
    self.id = Rectangle.id
    Rectangle.id += 1

  @property  
  def coords(self):
      return (self.left, self.right, self.bottom, self.top)

  def isSubrectangle(self, other):
    return (
      isSubinterval(self.left, self.right, other.left, other.right) and
      isSubinterval(self.bottom, self.top, other.bottom, other.top)
    )

  def intersects(self, other):
    return (
      intersects(self.left, self.right, other.left, other.right) and
      intersects(self.bottom, self.top, other.bottom, other.top)
    )

  def __repr__(self):
    return ("[%f,%f]x[%f,%f]" % (self.left, self.right, self.bottom, self.top))


def randomRect(ratio=0.1, scale=100):
  w = random() * ratio
  h = random() * ratio
  centerX = random() * (1 - w)
  centerY = random() * (1 - h)
  return Rectangle(
    scale*(centerX - w/2), scale*(centerX + w/2),
    scale*(centerY - h/2), scale*(centerY + h/2),
  )
```

Comparison with @Andrey's solution yielded an improvement of about an order of magnitude. Which is probably mostly due to the fact that python rtree uses an underlying C-implementation.

Comment: The `@property` allows `coords` to be called without parentheses? Neat. Yeah, as I said, the performance of this implementation cannot compete with a tuned C implementation. For now, I only cared about the asymptotic behavior and correctness. If one removes all the unnecessary repeated iterations, one probably could get an at least 4x faster implementation even in pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

If the rectangles are reasonably evenly distributed, you might save time by treating it as a 1-dimensional problem, concentrating on the X (or Y) axis first.

Each rectangle has a minimal and maximal X-coordinate, the X-coordinates of its top left and bottom right corners. Create two records for each rectangle, giving its minimal or maximal X-coordinate and a pointer to the rectangle. Sort these records into increasing order of X-coordinate and work through them in that order.

Maintain an array of rectangles ordered by minimal X-coordinate, inserting a record into it when you see its minimal X-coordinate and deleting a record from it when you see its maximal X-coordinate. Just before you delete a record, you can do a binary search in the array to find all of the records whose minimal X-coordinate is no more than the minimal X-coordinate of the record you are about to delete and whose maximal X-coordinate is at least that of the record you are about to delete. Check these to see if their Y-coordinates also contain the record you are about to delete. If so, you have found a record that completely contains the record you are about to delete. This should find all of the X-containments because the array contains records for every rectangle which overlaps the current X-point in the X dimension - they have been inserted and not yet deleted.

(in fact you will need to  be more careful than this if there are ties for the X-coordinate).